# Rails: find_by_name and current_user.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question about find_by_name  with additional condition - curent_user.id.

For example, I have models: User, Mood and Post.
One user has many moods and one mood has only one user. Mood name is not unique.

When user are typing his post, he can type (with autocomplete) and select his mood, but only created by himself.

Now I have this (this part works well):

```
<%= f.text_field :mood_name, {"data-provide"=>"some_autocomplete_script", "data-source"=>"#{Mood.where(:user_id => current_user.id).collect {|x| x.name}}"} %>
```

My Post model has:

```
  def mood_name
     mood.try(:name)
  end
  def mood_name=(name)
     self.mood = Mood.find_by_name(name)
  end
```

So, how can I find record by_name and by current_user.id ? Not just by name, name is not unique in the table, but it's unique per user.

ps. Current user is defined in application_controller:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

pps. Mood has user_id column, same as a post.
My form:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :somecontent %>
<%= f.text_field :mood_name, {"data-provide"=>"some_autocomplete_script", "data-source"=>"#{Mood.where(:user_id => current_user.id).collect {|x| x.name}}"} %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My post_controller:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create

@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.user_id = current_user.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
     #save actions
  else
    # else :)
  end
end
end
```

And relations:

```
One user has many posts and many moods
Every mood has one user and many posts (user_id)
Every post has one user and one mood (user_id and mood_id)
```

Comment: Mood has a user_id column, right? Did you try ´Mood.find_by_name_and_user_id(name, current_user.id)?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried, but in this case it returns "undefined local variable or method `current_user'" :(

Comment: Try to make Post has one Mood and pass `current_user.moods` in your post form as a collection.

Comment: Okay. As your Post has one Mood add `<%= f.colelction_select :mood_id, current_user.moods.all, m.id, m.title } %>`. Like that.

Comment: Heh :) Collection select is real simple. but it is not what I need. Every user has a lot of moods, so I use this solution http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead . So. I need another way to resolve this question :)

Comment: You can use autocomplete for `text_field` but with `:mood_id` not with `:mood_name`. It's simpler - you don't need to have extra methods which you have. Selecting mood has already both: user_id and name :)

Comment: With mood_id I've get "Couldn't find Mood with id=0". So I need to find name - not the first name in the Mood table, but the name with current_user.id. Here is two conditions and this is my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you cant use helper_method in a model.
Try to pass it through the method parameters like

```
def mood_name=(name, user)
   self.mood = Mood.find_by_name_and_user_id(name, user.id)
end
```

Then pass `current_user` where you call this method

Comment: Thanks, I think it's right way, but I can't understand where I need to put the second argument :-[

Comment: Maybe in controller? I dont completely understand what you are doing. Can you provide more code of your form, controller?

Comment: is there any way of allowing for the user of helper methods in models?